# How to avoid "error LNK2005:" (already defined stdlib functions) when compiling libpng with Microsoft Visual Studio '08?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, lnk2005

(Why I am trying to do this: I have had no luck in using the pre-built binaries for libpng on Windows (despite many hours of trial and error), and therefore am now trying to compile it myself. I found [this helpful blog post](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/building-libpng-in-visual-studio-2008/) concerning this, complete with a Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 project file, but unfortunately have still not been able to use it.)

It successfully compiles when linking to the zlib binary found [here](http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=bobobobo.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zlib.net%2Fzlib123-dll.zip), but when attempting to link it to a test file I receive the following:

```
    C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents>cl "C:\Documents and Settin
    gs\Administrator\My Documents\test.c" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\M
    y Documents\libpng.lib" -I "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\include"

    Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    test.c
    Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    /out:test.exe
    test.obj
    "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\libpng.lib"
    MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll) : error LNK2005: _abort already defined in LIBCMT.lib(
    abort.obj)
    MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fread already defined in LIBCMT.lib(
    fread.obj)
    MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib
    (malloc.obj)
    MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMT.lib(f
    ree.obj)
    MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in LIBCMT
    .lib(_file.obj)
    LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; u
    se /NODEFAULTLIB:library
    test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Could anyone care to shed some light as to how to fix these errors?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is that one of the two projects is using **Multi-threaded DLL** while the other is using **Multi-threaded** (without DLL in it) in Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code generation.

Happened to me several times.

Make sure to "synchronize" that setting even for release builds, and for each possible combination (debug, non debug, etc)

Comment: That... was absolutely amazing. Also, ditto, Sam.

Comment: Where does this setting appear in files that can be grepped? I can't find anything under the vcxproj files but I may be searching the wrong term.

Comment: Actually, just spotted this in a diff of the vcxproj today, I was mistakenly searching for the compiler flag /MDd instead of the corresponding descriptive text of the setting. Shows up as: `<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>`